# Listen on event during other event only

Tags: events, f#

How do I listen to MouseMove event, only after I have pressed my mouse button (MouseDown event)

Im basicly looking for Click->Drag->Release functionality in a F# forms application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can be nicely captured using the F# async workflows mechanism. I wrote an article about this (implementing exactly drag & drop kind of functionality) where you can find the details - See [Programming user interfaces with F# async workflows](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Programming-user-interfaces-using-f-sharp-workflows.aspx).

The sample application implements drawing where you push a button, then move the mouse (to define a rectangle) and then eventually release the button:

```
let rec drawingLoop(clr, from) = async {
   // Wait for the first MouseMove occurrence
   let! move = Async.AwaitObservable(form.MouseMove)
   if (move.Button &&& MouseButtons.Left) = MouseButtons.Left then
      // Refresh the window & continue looping
      drawRectangle(clr, from, (move.X, move.Y))
      return! drawingLoop(clr, from)
   else
      // Return the end position of rectangle
      return (move.X, move.Y) }

let waitingLoop() = async {
   while true do
      let! down = Async.AwaitObservable(form.MouseDown)
      let downPos = (down.X, down.Y)
      if (down.Button &&& MouseButtons.Left) = MouseButtons.Left then
         let! upPos = drawingLoop(Color.IndianRed, downPos)
         do printfn "Drawn rectangle (%A, %A)" downPos upPos }
```

The nice thing here is that you can pretty nicely express the logic - wait for `MouseDown` (inside `waitingLoop`), then call the `drawingLoop` function which waits for `MouseMove` until the button is released (and then transfers the control back to `waitingLoop` which starts waiting for another mouse down event).

Another version of a similar piece of code is in [Phil Trelford's fractal zoom, which uses the same gesture for zooming](http://trelford.com/blog/post/FractalZoom.aspx).

The complete source code is a part of [the Chapter 16 source code of Real-World Functional Programming](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp).

Comment: This does pretty much exactly what I try to achieve. But I have a lot to learn about Asynchronus workflows, and different operators in f#.
Maybe you could point me in the right direction with **&&&** and **let!** ?

Comment: `&&&` is "binary and" and `let! k = x:Async<T>` is awaiting the asynchronous operation then setting `k` to a variable of type `T` (at least in an async{} block)

Answer (score 2):

Attach the event listeners for move and up in the mouse down event, remove it in the up. This does mean the handler method needs to be a method (or you need to keep hold of the delegate used) to pass to the event's remove method.

(If this were for C# I would point you towards Rx—the Reactive Extensions—as this is perhaps the defining example, but I'm unsure how well Rx works with F#.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use something like this:

```
let setupDrag(target, fn) =
    let isDown = ref false
    target.MouseDown |> Event.add(fun _ -> isDown := true)
    target.MouseMove |> Event.filter(fun _ -> !isDown) |> Event.add(fn)
    target.MouseUp |> Event.add(fun( _ -> isDown := false)
```

In a real implementation, you may want to actually do other stuff when the transition starts, stops, and all those things. You may for example want to capture the pointer on target.